# Accessing groups with_items in playbook and template

Tags: ansible

The `groups.myNodes` seems to return an array of IP addresses. I need complex objects complete with any defined host variables. Also, I need my template to access the `item` host not the ansible host.

`item.someHostVariable` fails as the item has no such variable, although in fact it does.

```
- hosts: target
  tasks: 
    - name: foo
      template: src=foo.txt.template dest={{item.someHostVariable}}.txt
      with_items: ('{{groups.myNodes}}')
```

P.S. Ansible wants the parentheses, double handle-bars and quotes on the group reference. It's troubling the parser needs THAT much help to use a variable.

Comment: Clarification: I have a playbook with one inventory host, and a template task that loops over a different inventory group.  The template needs host details for the current "item", and the template statement in the playbook also uses the host details from the current "item".

Answer (score 0):

The groups list only includes the hostnames for the group, so `item` in this case is just the inventory_hostname- to get at its vars, you need to do `{{ hostvars[item].someHostVariable }}`.

Also: assuming you're using Ansible 2.x, you only need to quote the `with_items:` value to avoid the bare vars deprecation warning (the parens are superfluous).